# PEP8 mark the variable reference @pytest.fixture as "shadows name from outer scope"

Tags: python, pytest, pep8

I have one simple pytest problem,:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def config():
    return "abc"

def mytest(config):
    print(config)
```

The message mentioned that "Shadows name 'config' from out scope" in the line of `def mytest(config):`.

Any suggestion to handle this PEP8 message?

Comment: I would suggest renaming you `def config()` to `def get_config()`. But questin is kinda broad, because a lot of answers can apply to problem.

Comment: Who gave you the message?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on who is raising the warning, it can be suppressed like:

#### Suppress pylint warning:

```
# pylint: disable=R0801
def mytest(x_config):
    print(x_config)
```

#### Suppress pycharm warning:

```
# noinspection 801,PyShadowingNames
def mytest(x_config):
    print(x_config)
```